# how do I implement file browser code that requires extending an activity?

Tags: android, file, arraylist, listactivity

How can i implement a file browser, without exteniding the listactivity class? I'm trying to add an option in my app to choose a file browser to pick their own file to use instead of the default. I made a button, to move to the filebrowser list, but when i use the code `setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter);` It says i need to extend ListActivity. When i do this i have a problem running the app altogether. Any ideas of what i am doing wrong? How can i not have to extend the listactivity, because my app is not really only a list, it only needs to use the list. Thanks!

UPDATE-LOGCAT

```
01-15 09:39:22.399: D/AndroidRuntime(317): Shutting down VM
01-15 09:39:22.409: W/dalvikvm(317): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
01-15 09:39:22.409: E/AndroidRuntime(317): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2031)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at phil.H.com.HIITActivity.changesong(HIITActivity.java:132)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2026)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  ... 21 more
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at phil.H.com.HIITActivity.getDir(HIITActivity.java:216)
01-15 09:39:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  ... 25 more
01-15 09:39:22.509: I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 317 SIG: 3
01-15 09:39:22.509: I/dalvikvm(317): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
01-15 09:39:22.609: I/dalvikvm(317): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-15 09:44:22.559: I/Process(317): Sending signal. PID: 317 SIG: 9
01-15 09:44:22.659: E/JavaBinder(59): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
01-15 09:44:22.680: I/WindowManager(59): WIN DEATH: Window{44debcc8 phil.H.com/phil.H.com.HIITActivity paused=false}
01-15 09:44:22.680: I/ActivityManager(59): Process phil.H.com (pid 317) has died.
01-15 09:44:22.939: I/UsageStats(59): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in phil.H.com
01-15 09:44:23.559: W/InputManagerService(59): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 317 uid 10029
```

Comment: I believe, you can add ListView and you can try to setAdapter for the listview.

Comment: What do you mean by "When i do this i have a problem running the app altogether"? A `ListActivity` behaves just like any other `Activity`, and can contain any layout you want. The only difference is that it requires your layout to include a `ListView` with `android:id=@android:id/list`, and has build in methods for populating that `ListView`.

Comment: it says that it has closed unexpectedly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `ListActivity`. There just has to be a `ListView` object within the layout you use, as long as you use the right methods on it.

Set up a [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) in the XML file you inflate, then fetch it:

```
ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
```

Then, you can set its adapter:

```
myListView.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter);
```

The documentation has [an awesome tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) on a moderately advanced `ListView` implementation.

Comment: yes, but my activity does not have a listview object in its main layout. I need it to go into a secondary layout. It is created, but when extend the listactivity, it wont start my app. when i try it says the application has stopped unexpectedly.

Comment: As I said, you don't have to use `ListActivity`. Add a `ListView` to whichever layout you want to have the list, then populate it with items from your adapter.

Comment: yes, I tried your suggested implementation, but i get an error when doing this. It just stops unexpectedly. I will try to get my logcat up, and maybe someone knows what it means.

Comment: Something's null on line 216 of `HIITActivity.java`. Have a look there.

Comment: Yup, i found that there was textview, that i had not declared earlier.